# Successfully rewritten image URLs but content not being cached

Tags: asp.net, caching, url-rewriting

ASP.net app hosted on Microsoft Azure. Have successfully rewritten URLs of image files - for example:

```
/file/i/Logo/fed88a06-1157-4bbb-826d-365bdd8c89eb/png/logo.png
```

These show correctly in the web app - so the rewrite is working fine.

However, I cannot get these images to cache consistently across browsers:

- Safari shows that static images used on the site (such as a footer logo) are caching fine, but no re-written content is; loads every time.
- Chrome, however, appears to cache the content absolutely fine on a mac and does not reload any content - great.
- Firefox doesn't cache any dynamic content, just like Safari.

I have tried various web.config cache rules but cannot seem to get this to work.

This is the current web.config rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Cache friendly file links" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^file\/i\/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\/([0-9A-Za-z-]{36})\/([0-9A-Za-z-]{2,})\/([_0-9A-Za-z-\%\+]+)\.([0-9A-Za-z-]{2,})" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="file/image?{R:1}.{R:2}/{R:3}.{R:4}?{R:5}.{R:6}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

And in a SharedActionsController we have this:

```
[Route("file/image")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[OutputCache(Duration = 31536000, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Any)]
public ActionResult GetImage()
{
    var path = Request.Url.Query.TrimStart('?');

    var accessor = new FileAccessor(path, User);

    if (!accessor.IsAllowed())
    {
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(accessor.SecurityErrors);
    }

    return File(accessor.Document.FileData, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(accessor.Document.FileName));
}
```